# How do I make a website show up in a Google Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromebook

Basically, I have this chatting website.

I want it to open up the web app inside of a [popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), and I would also like for it to create a notification when I have unread messages.

I need to know if I can make it so it opens like it's in a website, or if I need to completely rewrite the coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can in principle try to embed an iframe in the popup to show the webapp, but a popup page is completely destroyed when you close it, so it won't stay connected that way.

You would probably need another way.

It does not seem like Hall has any public API that you can use.

So probably your only option is to use a content script to interact with Hall opened in a tab. If you're adventurous, you could try to embed an iframe in your background page and interact with it there, but Hall may disallow framing.

All that said, I'm not so sure Hall will appreciate creating alternative software to interact with it.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was going to use it for personal use anyway (I'm not willing to pay the $5 for "Developers fee" in the Google Webstore), but I guess I could try for their help. Tell them the idea I have, we work together on it, and then it goes on the webstore on their account. Thanks again for the help.